# Async/await is a fine syntactic sugar

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, c#-5.0

Can we say that the C# async/await pattern is some kind of 
(smart) sugar syntax ?

Because as far as I can see, at the very end, it "just" hides all the implementation of an (internal) worker thread for the programmer.

Comment: There's no worker thread.

Comment: Here are [a few articles you should read](https://docs.com/paulo-morgado/8860/async-await-general) to get what `async-await` really is.

Comment: By the way, even assembly is syntatic sugar around machine code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async/await` is indeed syntactic sugar, however, it doesn't just hide threads.  Just because you use `async` and `await` in a method does not mean that you are creating threads.

From the MSDN Article [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_Threads):

> The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be
>   created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async
>   method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current
>   synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the
>   method is active. You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound work to a
>   background thread, but a background thread doesn't help with a process
>   that's just waiting for results to become available.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, there is no CLR support for `await`. It goes away on compilation. Anything you can write with `await` you can write without it.

Awaiting tasks it is a fancy way of calling `ContinueWith` :)

Decompile an assembly that uses await to see how it works under the covers.

Comment: But what it compiles to does have support from the framework. Maybe the `async` and `await` keywords are syntactic sugar but the whole async-await paradigm aren't.

Comment: You can write all such library support yourself. You can write your own TaskAwaiter which is the only thing required to replace. In fact the async targeting pack does that. await works on 4.0 which predates await.

Comment: You can do that for many features (e.g. LINQ) and I still wouldn't call them "just" syntactic sugar. If only changes to the CLR aren't syntactic sugar that's leaves just a few.

Comment: LINQ query expressions certainly are purely syntactic sugar. The library component is not. Anyone can write it. That said it would be fair to say that all of C# is syntactic sugar... This concept is weakly defined I guess.

Comment: I agree. That's why I said that maybe just the transformation from an async method to the state machine is syntactic sugar, but the TAP feature as a whole is not.

Comment: Indeed. It took me a long time to realize that await is just a fancy way of doing ContinueWith. It does NOT create a worker thread. That still requires Task.Factory.StartNew() and equivalents.